# core data sqlite and other databases to merge

Tags: ios, database, core-data

Right now im developing an ios app that has a very complex core data graph but I'm also planning it to work for android and other devices and with a webpage.

The webpage and the other devices can be managed with a number of database but in ios i'm using the core data since i find more friendly to program. My question is if were to make a server for the entire application ecosystem (web, android, html, ios) would i be able to merge all data in a single server database including the core data one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly merge the data, but not the database files. If you're storing and/or syncing data using a server, you'll need to define some kind of server API for client access. An iOS app using Core Data could also make use of that API to communicate with the server. So, yeah, should be do-able.

Your server side code will almost certainly be something SQL-based, so when communicating back and forth you'll probably end up mapping Core Data entities to SQL tables. That's fine, so long as the server API doesn't require too much SQL-specific, non-Core Data style data. For example: Core Data doesn't generally use anything like join tables, since it has real many-to-many relationships. It's possible to make an iOS app convert between Core Data relationships and SQLisms like that (I've done it) but it's kind of a pain in the ass. It's not generally necessary though-- decent server APIs don't simply expose the entire table structure in its raw form.